# htaccess rewrite regex issue

Tags: regex, .htaccess

My current URL is:

```
http://www.domain.com/param1/ID
```

But I need the following URL to show the content of my current URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/param2/param1/ID-page-name
```

So when page with this URL is loaded:

```
http://www.domain.com/param2/param1/ID-page-name
```

Content of this URL should show up:

```
http://www.domain.com/param1/ID
```

Basically stripping out `param2` and `page-name`.

The following code did not work in htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]*)/param1/([^/]*)
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/param1/([^/]*)$ /param1/$2
```

Please help.

**EDIT**: Looks like this line `RewriteEngine On` causes 500 server error. No idea what it could be. `ModRewrite` is enabled in `httpd.conf`.

**EDIT 2**: My current htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A604800
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|ico)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

redirect /url1 http://www.domain.com/url2


#RewriteEngine On
```

When I uncomment the last line `RewriteEngine On` - the 500 error occurs.

Comment: You will need to edit in the contents of your htaccess file if we are to help you with the 500 server error.

Comment: @Howlin, your suggestion below also caused 500 error. How else can I edit it?

Comment: What exactly is in your htaccess file?

Comment: @Howlin, added into edit.

Comment: If `RewriteEngine On` is causing 500 then `mod_rewrite` isn't enabled.

Comment: This is not the case, checked httpd.conf, and tried <ifmodule> directives.

Comment: Check httpd.conf if `AllowOverride FileInfo` (or: `All`) is set, which is necessary for mod_rewrite to work. Related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache

Comment: Check your Apache error log for the actual error

Comment: Please advise how to, file is >1gb, can't download or view it. Can I empty it out or gzip and start from blank?

Comment: Ok, looked up error log. When ModRewrite is enabled, whole site gets redirected to a subfolder, although there are no such redirect directives in htaccess file. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like another.php is executed before index.php, but when modrewrite is enabled, index.php gets higher priority. Can this be the case? If so, how to enable modrewrite while keeping the priorities of the files?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^/]+)/([^-]+)- /$1/$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/param1/([0-9]+)-(.*)$ /param1/$2 [L]
```